# In how many ways can four distinctive letters be posted in 6 post boxes such that any two go in same post box and remaining go to different boxes?

Tags: combinatorics, permutations, combinations

I have tried to solve it in two different ways. But I ended up with different answers.

- **First method**
  There are $\binom{4}{2}=6$ different $2$ letter combinations from a set of $4$ letters.
  With the remaining letters, the first has $5$ possible choices, and the last one has $4$.
  So there are in total $(6×6)×5×4=720$ ways to arrange the letters in the post boxes within the given criteria.
- **Second method**
  The first letter (among $4$ possible choices) has $6$ possible choices for the post box.
  The second one has $5$ possible choices among the $3$ remaining letters.
  The remaining two can go in any of the four postboxes left, in order to satisfy the requirement that there must be a post box with 2 letters.
  So, in total there are $(4×6)×(3×5)×4=1440$ ways.

I do not see any logical flaws in the arguments made in each method.
I do think the first one is correct.

Please, point out any flaws in my reasoning.

Comment: Here’s a pointer that can help you reason clearly and correctly about counting problems like this. Where you wrote, “There are 6 ways to choose the two letters that go together,” I’d suggest instead, “There are $4 \choose 2$ ways…” And then two sentences later, “So there are ${4 \choose 2} \times \cdots$” This reminds you—and informs others—what your reasoning was and makes it easier to find errors.

Comment: Thank you very much for your suggestion. You see I am new here,  so I will make sire to apply your suggestion next time for sure.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Denote letters in {**A**, **B**, **C**, **D**} and boxes in {**u**, **v**, **x**, **y**, **z**, **w**}.

In the 2nd way you mentioned:

- Choose letter **A**, and it goes into box **u**.
- Choose letter **B**, and it goes into box **v**.
- Other two letters (**C** and **D**) goes into box **x**.

compared with

- Choose letter **B**, and it goes into box **v**.
- Choose letter **A**, and it goes into box **u**.
- Other two letters (**C** and **D**) goes into box **x**.

They are two identical ways, but counted twice. (Not surprisingly, 1440 divided by 2 gives 720.)

Comment: ah, i posted ess'ly the same right after!

Answer (score 4):

In your second approach, suppose the letters are $A,B,C,D$. You say:

> One of the letters is to be chosen among the four letters which can be posted in 6 ways. And one of the letters is to be chosen among the remaining three which can be posted in 5 ways.

But, in this approach, you are counting e.g. $A$ in box one then $B$ in box two **and also** $B$ in box two then $A$ in box one. This double-counts the total outcomes; indeed, $1440 \div 2 = 720$ as desired.

Comment: What do I need to do if I have to answer the question considering the individual letters first like in the second method? I mean could you please answer the question eliminating the error I made in the second approach? I can't just divide it in the end, right?

Answer (score 1):

In your second calculation, you have 4×6×3×5×4, or (4×3)×(6×5×4). That is, you are there to be 4 permute 2 ways of choosing two letters (and the other two are then chosen by default), and 6 permute 3 ways of choosing the locations. But in your first calculation, you have four choose ways of choosing the pair, and the singletons are selected by default. This is the crux of the discrepancy: do you have 4×3/2 ways of choosing two letters, or 4×3? The answer is that your first calculation is correct: there are six, not twelve, ways of splitting the letters up into two singletons and one pair. It doesn't matter the order in which you choose letters to be singletons.

Answer (score 1):

At the beginning ,I have 4 letters A,B,C,D; I want to have 3 group-of-letters, I have $4 \times 3/2=6$ ways to choose a couple of letters, so I have $6$ ways to build my $3$ 'group-of-letters'.

I want to know how many options to post these $3$ groups in $6$ boxes : $ 6 \times 5 \times 4 $
Final result is $6 \times ( 6 \times 5 \times 4) =720$